# JavaScript: New Blob function output

Tags: javascript, blob, newline

Is it possible to print to a new line while using the new blob() function.

The code I have is:

```
var textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
var textToWrite = "";
for(var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; ++i){
  textToWrite = textToWrite + textBoxes[i].value;
  console.log(textToWrite);
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite],{type:'text/plain'});
```

I want to print a newline between each textbox.

Comment: `textToWrite = textToWrite + textBoxes[i].value + '\n';` ?

Comment: Your code is missing the closing brace }

Comment: textToWrite = textToWrite + textBoxes[i].value + '\n'; prints each to a new line in the console, but not in the fiel.

Comment: I have the  } lower down

Comment: `} lower down` is probably a bug. Why would you want to create as many blobs as you have textboxes ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add it as a string literal.

```
for(var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; ++i){
    textToWrite += textBoxes[i].value + '\n';
}
console.log(textToWrite);
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite],{type:'text/plain'});
```

Comment: That will only right a new line to the console. 

it's :
'var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite],{type:'text/plain'});'

That writes it to the text file

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You said, you wanted the new line between the textbox values. This is what my code does, first add the newlines to the string in the variable `textToWrite`, then `console.log` it, and finally write it to the file.

Comment: If you don't find newlines in your file, probably you did not overwrite it.

Comment: Your code does a line between the text boxes for the console output. and returns a result of :  one <line> two <line> three
Box 1
Box 2
Box 3 

But I want the output file to print that way but it is printing like this:      one <space> two <space> three.    Box 1 Box 2 Box 3

Comment: How are you looking at the file? With text pad or with your navigator?

Comment: Because a newline in a browser shows as a space, unless it in a <pre> tag. You say the newlines in my code *are* spaces, I think they just *show* as spaces.